# What is the meaning of the terms "query" and "zone" with respect to a Dynamic DNS service?

Tags: networking, dns, ip-camera, ddns

I'm installing an IP Camera in our home and figured I needed a Dynamic DNS. Though, I'm not sure what to look for. So I got this pricing for Google's Cloud DNS service and can anyone point what the most generic terms are (Queries, Zone, etc) and which category should I be looking at.

https://cloud.google.com/dns/pricing

I'm asking for interpretation of these terms, which are also listed with other competing DDNS service, so this shouldn't be considered product recommendation.

Comment: Just make sure your camera isn’t Internet-accessible. Otherwise it *will* join a botnet sooner or later. // Also, why not use something free like No-IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well looking at it, it goes like this:

- Queries: How many times someone goes to the website (dns name)
- Zone: How many dns names you can issue (standard is 5)

Sinds you only use 1 IP camera you might aswell go for the standard that will cost $5/month.

Comment: I was actually afraid that the "Query" is almost synonymous with bandwidth. So to get it straight, as long as I only refresh the page once (say in a browser) that's considered only 1 query. It doesn't matter how long I leave it or if I let the video keep on streaming?

Comment: A Query in this instance is a call to your website/camera so yes. using 10,000,000 you will never reach even if you keep spamming F5 for the rest of the month. Even if you used 1 each second you will only be able to achieve 2,592,000

Comment: Awesome. Thnx for the help.

Comment: isn't it how often the domain name is looked up? So if a high TTL is set, multiple queries will not hit google's server until the cached result has expired

Comment: @user45891 I didnt take caching in account but cache free refreshes, But yes sinds he only makes use of 1 IP camera this would he a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need dynamic DNS to access an IP camera when you are away from home (I assume that is your intent), you just need UPnP enabled on your home router and then you need to know your public IP address to use in your camera app, which can be found simply by searching "public IP" on Google from a browser at home.

Google Cloud DNS is **way overkill** for what you'd need if you decided to take that jump.  Any registrar that you'd setup your own DNS domain through can provide hosting services (usually included) that would be more than adequate.  Google is your friend ... search "domain name registrar".